# Debian instance has two Kernels after installing Intel PCIe SSD drivers - one with Black screen

Tags: debian, linux-kernel, nvidia, intel, proprietary-drivers

I am using Debian 8 and after installing Intel PCIe ssd drivers I noticed that the are two kernels. The kernel which has the Intel drivers installed does not display the desktop, only a black screen.

The kernel details from running `uname -a` are:

```
Linux Debian 3.19.0 #1 SMP Thou Jul 22 21:42:40 EST 2015 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

and

```
Linux debian 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.7-ckt11-1+deb8u2 (2015-07-17) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Kernel 3.19.0 is the default kernel. Prior to installing Intel's PCIe ssd drivers this kernel did not exist.

I followed the installation procedure outlined by page 4 of Intel's instructions: [link to Intel documentation](http://downloadmirror.intel.com/23929/eng/Intel_Linux_NVMe_Driver_Reference_Guide_330602-002.pdf).
This involved downloading a kernel, then using make and menuconfig commands

I installed official Nvidia drivers (using a .run file) in the 3.16.0-4 kernel. I am still able to successfully boot into this kernel.

After logging into kernel 3.19.0, I used CTRL+ALT+F1 to run `dmesg | grep -i error` and received the below response:

```
[3.638817] EXT4-fs (sda1): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
[3.954107] Error: Driver 'pcspkr' is already registered, aborting...
[4.194389] nouveau: probe of 0000:01:00.0 failed with error -22
```

I am relatively new to Linux and I don't understand why there are two kernels? How do I merge the two kernels or how do I install both Intel and Nvidia drivers in a single kernel? What caused a new kernel to be created?
I appreciate your help.